# How to hide field from entity display view programmatically?

Tags: 7, entities

I am adding field inside module.install file to specified entity. I want to hide this field from display. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anyway found solution, example of field instance:

```
field_create_instance(array(
    'field_name' => FIELD_GALLERY_VIEW_FIELD_NAME,
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'bundle' => 'article',
    'label' => t('Choose gallery View'),
    'description' => t('Gallery view type for display gallery field collection'),
    'widget' => array(
        'type' => 'OPTIONS_SELECT',
        'weight' => 0,
        'settings' => array('size' => 50),
    ),
    'display' => array(
        'default' => array(
            'label' => 'hidden',
            'settings' => array(),
            'weight' => 1,
            'type' => 'hidden'
        ),
        'teaser' => array(
            'label' => 'hidden',
            'settings' => array(),
            'type' => 'hidden',
        ),
    ),
    'required' => TRUE,
));
```

Comment: It's included in the [docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/group/field/7.x) for ['display']['default']['type'] → "The type of the display formatter, or 'hidden' for no display."