# How to hide a view programmatically?

Tags: 7, views

I need hide a view when some GET param exists. It should be hidden like if you insert 'Global: Null' in contextual filter(It hides view if no results). This view placed in panel*

I tried to find the solution but failed. How to do this?

Comment: check this I think this may help you.. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51731/how-to-hide-field-from-entity-display-view-programmatically

Comment: This is about fields. But I need hide view.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are adding it as a block to a specific path. 
If yes, follow the steps below:

1. Go to the block configuration
2. Scroll down to the Visibility Settings
3. Click on "Pages" tab
4. Select the option "Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE (experts only)"
5. Write your PHP logic to read the GET parameters and return true only if the specific parameter you are looking for is not found.

Comment: First, I don't use blocks I use content panes. Second, how do I know that view have empty result?

Comment: Ew ew ew ew ew ew. Don't use PHP inside views, you should be using hooks.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to specify a validation criteria in a contextual filter, could be Global:null as you said. Then choose the action you want to take when validation fails.
You can implement your validation logic in PHP, preferably inside a function in your code and you just call it from the view.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you override the views template and add a if statement, something like `if (function == true) { //do something }` (Sorry, really horrible in PHP...)